# How to use Attribute Based Access Control (ABAC)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, access-control

I know we can implement access control in chaincode by using ABAC.
For example, there are 2 organizations.
Org1's users have an attribute: `org_id=org1`.
Org2's users have an attribute: `org_id=org2`.

But, if fabric-ca-server doesn't have a function to make users have a designated attribute in the organization, users can disguise their attribute with the help of fabric-ca's admin.
(I mean that Org1's users can have an attribute: `org_id=org2` if they really want to do.)

Ultimately, I think that ABAC in chaincode has no meaning.
How can I ABAC? Is there any suitable use case?

Answer (score 1):

When users are registered in the CA they can be assigned attributes by the person/ID that is registering them - e.g. using the fabric-ca-client command line:

`fabric-ca-client register --id.name clare --id.secret hellothere --id.maxenrollments -1 --id.attrs 'department=Finance:ecert,role=buyerapproval:ecert'`

The attributes will be present in the Certificae when `clare` enrolls and can then in this example, role and department can be checked in the Smart Contract (chaincode) when `Clare` submits a transaction.

(it is necessary to have the flag `ecert` on the attribute to ensure it is included in the certificate.)

The attributes are set in the CA so only apply to a certificate that is issued at enrollment after the attributes have been set - existing certificates are not modified.

Comment: I know how to use Fabric CA to assign attribute. What I want to say is that ABAC has no meaning if each organization manages Fabric CA by itself. Because each organization can assign any attribute freely, we can't control each organization's access to the chaincode function by ABAC. What do you think?

Comment: The Client Identity object in the Smart Contract which exposes the Attributes also has the "mspId" and the "id" available - isn't that enough to identify the Organisation?